# Best way to validate a string in js

Tags: javascript

I need to make sure that my string is a number and for doing that, I was using isNaN function and everything was working but I got a problem when I typed in my input field '0e1'.

I was wondering what's the best way to check if my string is a number and without scientific notation

Comment: `isNaN('0e1')` *should* be `false`.  That's correct.

Comment: It's not really clear from your question if you **do** or **do not** want to match things like `0e1`

Answer (score 2):

Try using regex. Here are some examples. The result is null if no match was found.

```
alert("0e1".match(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/))    // null
alert("1".match(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/))      // 1
alert("-1".match(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/))     // -1
alert("1.0".match(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/))    // 1.0
alert("-1.5".match(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/))   // -1.5
alert("-1.5 4".match(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/)) // null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your input to only be an integer or float do this instead;

```
var input = '0e1';

if(!isNaN(input) && (parseInt(input, 10).toString() == input || parseFloat(input).toString() == input)){
    //This is a valid number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the method you are using is fine.  You have one problem with your code:

`isNaN()` should be `!isNaN()`.  Remember, `isNaN()` checks if the number is NotaNumber.  `!isNaN() checks if it IS a number.

`isNaN(0e1)` *should* return false because *0e1 is a number!*  I know, it's kind of confusing.

`!isNaN(0e1)` will return TRUE because `!isNan()` checks if a value IS a number.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The OP is trying to check if my string is a number **without scientific notation**. In addition `isNaN` will fail in some edge cases like `!isNaN('') === true`, this should be the correct way to implement an `IsNumeric` function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/63011 (but it's not what the OP is asking)

Comment: I would disagree with you.  It's hard to tell from the way the OP asked the question, but I think he DOES want to use scientific notation.  Otherwise he wouldn't of mentioned it.

Comment: quoting his words: *check if my string is a number and without scientific notation*

Comment: His question has been edited since I posted my answer.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti, quote from original question: *I was using isNaN function but it's not working maybe because it looks like scientific notation.*

Comment: His question was edited before you posted your answer, but I agree that it's not clear :)

Comment: @PaoloMoretti, yes I see that, but I wrote it before and forgot to hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

isNaN() function determines whether a value is an illegal number, so if it is **not a number**. The good thing about isNaN function is, that is suportet by all browsers (ch, ie, ff, op, sf).

```
function myFunction() {
    var a = isNaN(123) + "<br>";
    var b = isNaN(-1.23) + "<br>";
    var c = isNaN(123-456) + "<br>";
    var d = isNaN("Hello") + "<br>";
    var e = isNaN("2014/11/19") + "<br>";

    var result = a + b + c + d + e;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;
}
```

So result would be: If value is a number return "False" if is not a number return "True".

You can test it on JsFiddle: [isNaN()](http://jsfiddle.net/ffk4b0rh/)